# KSQLDB table RIGHT JOIN

Tags: ksqldb

I have two tables in KSQLDB

```
Person
------
Id     PK
Name
```

```
Activity
--------
Id     PK
Name
PersonId
```

Joining "FROM Activity LEFT JOIN Person" works fine.
But I want to "FROM Person LEFT JOIN Activity"

```
CREATE TABLE Person_Activity AS
  SELECT *
  FROM Person
  LEFT JOIN Activity on Person.Id = Activity.PersonId
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

But I'm getting: `Invalid join condition: table-table joins require to join on the primary key of the right input table. Got Person.Id = Activity.PersonId`

I then tried full outer join

```
CREATE TABLE Person_Activity AS
  SELECT *
  FROM Activity
  FULL OUTER JOIN Person on Person.Id = Activity.PersonId
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

But got this instead:
`Invalid join type: full-outer join not supported for foreign-key table-table join. Got Activity [FULL] OUTER JOIN Person.`

Are there any other way to do it?

Comment: Hi, can you swap LEFT and RIGHT tables to have the person_activity on the left? If it's OK to only get the persons that are in the activity table, and not all persons from the list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I need person without activity too.